# What's the fatest way to calculate in command line?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, fish

Is there a faster way to calculate in command line the following:

```
echo "4 * 5" | bc
```

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: Too many `echo`s.

Comment: `bc <<< "4 * 5"`

Comment: Do you mean faster as in _less keystrokes_ or as in _lower execution time_?

Comment: @heavyd: I use Fish Shell.

Comment: @mpy: less keystrokes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to add a solution for the *Z shell*, unfortunately I know almost nothing about *fish*, so that I could adapt this for fish syntax. Sorry!

I define a funcion `c`:

```
function c { echo $@ | bc }
```

And I set an alias for `c`, so that no file globbing takes place (and I can omit the quotes around expressions especially including a star:

```
alias c="noglob c"
```

Then I can do calculations like this:

```
$ c 4*5
20
$ c 1.5*2^8
384.0
```

That are 3 keystrokes (including the final `ENTER`) more than the actual expression to be calculated. Can be improved... perhaps with keybindings.

Comment: This also works in case of `fizsh`, that's close :)

Answer (score 4):

**POSIX-compatible Shells** (`dash` `ksh` `bash` `zsh` and many more)

There's a built-in method for that. Use `$(())` construction to do it:

```
echo $((4 * 5))
```

It does not call any functions, so it's faster.

Let's compare the ways (`zsh`):

```
$ time ( echo "4 * 5" | bc )
20
( echo "4 * 5" | bc; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 61% cpu 0.007 total

$ time ( echo $((4 * 5)) )
20
( echo $((4 * 5)); )  0.00s user 0.00s system 48% cpu 0.001 total
```

However, `$(())` has a lot of restrictions and is capable to do only basic arithmetical operations.

**C Shells** (`csh` `tcsh`)

I don't think there is a one-expression solution in **C Shell**s. However, it is possible to do the following:

```
@ i = 4 * 5 ; printf "$i\n"
```

**Fish**

Probably, `math "4 * 5"` works faster.

Answer (score 2):

A more general answer than the better (in this case) `$(( ))` answer is to use `<<<`

e.g. `bc <<< "4 * 5"` Here we don't need to use `echo`, we just send the argument into stdin.

Comment: Lol, never thought of it.

Comment: That isn't work with fish shell...

Comment: This is bash shell